# Laravel 5: Eloquent - order by relation when returning single record

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, relation

im trying build query in eloquent with data sorted by relation. Imagine this DB structure:

**TABLE: Station**

```
id
name
...
```

**TABLE: station_status:**

```
id
station_id
status_type_id
date
...
```

**TABLE: status_type:**

```
id
description
...
```

**MODELS**

```
class Station extends \Eloquent
{
    public function stationStatus() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\StationStatus', 'station_id', 'id');
    }
}

class StationStatus extends \Eloquent
{
    public function statusType() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\StatusType', 'id', 'status_type_id');
    }
}

class StatusType extends \Eloquent
{
    ...
}
```

Now the question. How can i query Station model by station ID, but sort by related status types description?

So far i have:

```
// This just do not work
$query = Station::join('station_status', 'station.id', '=',   'station_status.station_id')
    ->join('status_type', 'station_status.status_type_id', '=', 'status_type.id')
    ->orderBy('status_type.description', 'ASC')
    ->select(['stations.*'])
    ->with(['stationStatus.statusType']
    ->find(110);
```

I think the problem is that i'm not returning collection but only one item using find() method, how can i overcome this problem?

Many thanks for any help !

Comment: Apologies if I'm not understanding the question but can you not use the get() method at the end instead of find and use ->where('station.id', '=', 110) ?

Comment: If you are loading only one record then there is nothing to order. Do you want to order the ralated records?

Comment: Yes i want to have related records ordered, so when i access, $query->stationStatus they are ordered by status_type description

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$query = Station::with(['stationStatus' => function($q){
    $q->join('status_type', 'station_status.status_type_id', '=', 'status_type.id')
    ->orderBy('status_type.description', 'ASC');
}])->find(110);
```

With is a convienent way of getting the related objects, but it doesn't perform a join. It performs a new query and attaches all the elements to your collection. You can add your own logic to the query, like I did with `$q->orderBy(...)`.

Comment: This would sort the related (eagreloaded) records (`statusType`).

Comment: Yes, I think I misunderstood the question. The ->find(110) threw me off.

Comment: No this do not work properly, actualy SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'description' in 'order clause'

Comment: Edited it. Now it should get you Station with id 1 and all the stationStatuses  (and their statusType) ordered by statusType description.